# Extracting a range of keys from leveldb or redis

Tags: node.js, redis, leveldb

I would like to extract a range of keys from either leveldb or redis. For example i have the following key structure;

```
group:1/member:1
group:1/member:1/log:1
group:1/member:1/log:2
group:1/member:1/log:3
group:1/member:1/log:4
group:1/member:2
group:1/member:2/log:1
group:1/member:2/log:2
group:1/member:3
group:1/member:3/log:1
```

I would like to get all members(members:1, members:2, members:3) but i do not want their log entries to be included in results(there may be thousands of logs). What is the best approach to achieving this using a KV store like redis or leveldb?

Comment: Unsolicited advice: your suggested key structure actually makes it harder to use commands like SCAN in redis.  I would suggest using a structure more like `group:<GroupId>` -> list of members; `member:<MemberID>` -> member data; `log:<MemberId>:<LogId>` -> log file.  Nesting the keys into a hierarchy like this can also force your application to jump through unfortunate hoops to get lower-level data.

Answer (score 1):

For LevebDB, you can use the [leveldb::Iterator](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/include/leveldb/iterator.h) to iterate the key space, and only keep the keys that match your pattern.

For Redis, you can use the [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) command to scan the key space with a pattern.